# How to build docker image when using dynamic docker agent?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-agent

How to build the docker images when running docker as jenkins agents for the build.

I am trying to understand the different ways we can build the docker images

Jenkins Installed on virtual machine - centos 7, on the same machine installed docker.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3.6.2-jdk-11'
        }
    }
    environment {
        IMAGE_NAME=readMavenPom().getArtifactId()
        BUILD_NUMBER="${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
        GITLAB_URL="xxxx"
        IMAGE_VERSION=readMavenPom().getVersion()
        GIT_URL="xxxx"
        GIT_CRED_ID="xxxx"
        DOCKER_REPOURL="xxxx"
    }
    options {
        timestamps()
    }
    stages {
        stage ('Checkout') {
            steps {
                echo 'Build Started ...'
                checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/jenkins_build']], browser: [$class: 'GitLab', repoUrl: "${GITLAB_URL}", version: '11.10'], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: "${GIT_CRED_ID}", url: "${GIT_URL}"]]]
                configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: '392b1fe8-8ccd-4b8a-a73b-1d745a6bd03d', variable: MAVEN_GLOBAL_SETTINGS{
                    sh 'mvn -gs $MAVEN_GLOBAL_SETTINGS clean package '
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Publish') {
            steps {
                echo 'Build and Deploy to Nexus ...'
                withDockerRegistry(credentialsId: 'nexus_docker_creds', url: 'xxxxxx') {
                    sh '''
            docker --version
                        docker build -t "${DOCKER_REPOURL}"/"${IMAGE_NAME}":"${IMAGE_VERSION}"
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```sh
[Pipeline] withDockerRegistry
14:53:32  $ docker exec --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** --env ******** 9a2be9d46c2f9961d1852d2322e64a20a1b4bade1c55d297f4f1d2d2943cc7b4 docker login -u admin -p ******** https://xxxxx
14:53:34  OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"docker\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
[Pipeline] // withDockerRegistry
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timestamps
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 9a2be9d46c2f9961d1852d2322e64a20a1b4bade1c55d297f4f1d2d2943cc7b4
$ docker rm -f 9a2be9d46c2f9961d1852d2322e64a20a1b4bade1c55d297f4f1d2d2943cc7b4
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: docker login failed
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue